# Create dynamic category menu in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to coding and PHP and I want to create an online shop for a school project. I want simple code that selects categories in my DB shows them on a home page and when click on it select all things in that category and shows them. I wrote code that can create buttons for each category that are in my database but I have no idea how write code that when the user clicks on a button selects that category.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456789";
$dbname = "shopdb";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT  category FROM good ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo  "category: ";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<button>$row[category]</button>" ;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only php you can redirect the use after he clicks the category.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $category = $row["category"];
     echo "<a href=’?category=$category’>$category</a>" ;
}
```

Make the link look like a button with css.

So when the user clicks on the link it redirects him to the same page he is currently but it adds the 
`?category` in the end of it. `home.php?category=clothes`.

In the same page use `$_GET` to get the `?category` value from the url.

And make a query to get your items for the category.

```
if(isset($_GET[’category’])){

    $category = $_GET[’category’];   
    $sql = mysqli_prepare(”SELECT * FROM items WHERE category = ?”);    
    $sql->bind_param(”ss”, $category);   
    $sql->execute();    

    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row[”name”];

    }

}
```

And you should do this before you close your mysqli connection.

You may need to change the query because i don’t know your tables and you could maby wrap the `while` loop inside a div or something. But i hope you get the basic idea.

If you want it to look more fancy you could do the same with jQuery and Ajax since you have the jQuery tag.

Make a click function for your category buttons. You should add classes on them. `<button class=’category’>$row[category]</button>`.

Make another file for your ajax requests to get your items for the category.

```
$(”.category”).click(function() {

    var category = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: ”items.php?category=” + category,
        type: ”GET”,
        success: function(items) {
            console.log(items);
        }
    });
});
```

In your `items.php` or whatever you named it you can basically do the same php code that i wrote earlier.

Get the category name from the url with `$_GET[’category’]` and use it to search the items from your database.

The `items` variable that we have as parameter in the ajax success function, now contains everything that `items.php` echo out.

Now continue to handle the data in the `items` variable and display it.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass your php variable in your html code. After in your html code try this.

```
   <?php while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>
        <button><?php echo $row[category] ?></button>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You can also use `"...{$row['category']} ..."` for interpolating more complex variable references.